# Connecting with ftplib via FTP proxy in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to download files from FTP. It works fine at home but it doesn't work when I run through company's network. I know there is something to do with proxy. I have looked at a few posts regarding the proxy issue in Python. I have tried to set up a connection to the proxy. It works ok for url but it failed when connecting to FTP. Does anyone know a way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

```
import os
import urllib
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
from getpass import getpass
from urllib.request import urlopen, ProxyHandler, HTTPHandler,     HTTPBasicAuthHandler, \
                                build_opener, install_opener

user_proxy = "XXX"
pass_proxy = "YYY"
url_proxy = "ZZZ"
port_proxy = "89"
url_proxy = "ftp://%s:%s@%s:%s" % (user_proxy, pass_proxy, url_proxy,     port_proxy)
authinfo = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"ftp" : url_proxy})

# build a new opener that adds authentication and caching FTP handlers
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support, authinfo,
                                 urllib.request.CacheFTPHandler)

# install it
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

#url works ok
f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com/')
print(f.read(500))
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

#ftp is not working
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp:/ba1.geog.umd.edu', 'user', 'burnt_data')
```

The error message I got:

```
730     # and socket type values to enum constants.
731     addrlist = []
--> 732     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
733         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
734         addrlist.append((_intenum_converter(af, AddressFamily),

gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

I can connect via the proxy using FileZilla by selecting custom FTP proxy with specification:

```
USER %u@%h %s
PASS %p
ACCT %w
```

[FTP Proxy using FileZilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4vtF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting using an FTP proxy.

*FTP proxy cannot work with HTTP, so your test against `http://` URL to `www.google.com` is completely irrelevant and does not prove anything.*

FTP proxy works as an FTP server. You connect to the proxy, instead of to the actual server. And then use some special syntax of a username (or other credentials) to specify your actual target FTP server and its credentials. In your case the special syntax of username is `user@host user_proxy`. Your proxy expects the proxy password in FTP `ACCT` command.

This should work for your specific case:

```
host_proxy = '192.168.149.50'
user_proxy = 'XXX'
pass_proxy = 'YYY'

user = 'user'
user_pass = 'burnt_data'
host = 'ba1.geog.umd.edu'

u = "%s@%s %s" % (user, host, user_proxy)

ftp = ftplib.FTP(host_proxy, u, user_pass, pass_proxy)
```

No other code should be needed (`urllib` or any other).

If the proxy uses a custom port (not 21), use this:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect(host_proxy, port_proxy)
ftp.login(u, user_pass, pass_proxy)
```