# Using python to connect ftp with ftp proxy

Tags: python, proxy, ftp

I am trying to use python to connect a FTP sever and download a file. But I meet troubles when trying to connect to the file server.
I can use filezilla to connect to the server.
There are 3 connection information I use in filezilla(as picture):

1. proxy host/ proxy_user/ proxy_password
2. host/ username/ password
3. generic proxy: proxy host/ proxy user/ proxy password

But I didn't find related code how to use generic proxy in the python code.
So far I have tried these two scripts. How can I resolve this error?
Please help me for the same.

Thanks in Advance Guys!

1.

```
def ftp_login(proxy_host, proxy_user, proxy_password, host, user, password, account):
    ftp = FTP()
    ftp.connect(proxy_host)
    # error on this code
    ftp.login(user=proxy_user, passwd=proxy_password) 

    ftp.sendcmd(f"USER {user}@{host} {proxy_user}")
    ftp.sendcmd(f"PASS {password}")
    ftp.sendcmd(f"ACCT {account}")

    return ftp
import ftplib
# Replace the placeholders with your actual values
proxy_host = "proxy_host"
proxy_user = "proxy_user"
proxy_password = "proxy_password"

host = "host"
user = "user"
password = "password"
account = proxy_password

ftp_connection = ftp_login(proxy_host, proxy_user, proxy_password, host, user, password, account)
```

return error message

```
530-
530-Usage: USER username@hostname proxyusername
530-       PASS password
530        ACCT proxypassword
```

2. reference by [Connecting with ftplib via FTP proxy in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167538/connecting-with-ftplib-via-ftp-proxy-in-python)

```
# import ftplib
import ftplib

proxy_host = "proxy_host"
proxy_user = "proxy_user"
proxy_password = "proxy_password"

host = "host"
user = "user"
password = "password"

u = f"{user}@{proxy_host} {proxy_user}"
print(u)
ftp = ftplib.FTP(host, u, password, proxy_password)
```

return error message

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Finally the type of ftp proxy I use:

```
USER %u@%h %s
PASS %p
ACCT %w
```

filezilla proxy setting picture:

[image]
[image]